# okHttp always timeout when POST a large body

Tags: android, post, timeout, okhttp

I use okHttp do a POST request, it works when the fields String.length less than about 500.

code like this, a regular way to use okHttp:

```java
Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
builder.url(getHostname() + getUrl());
builder.post(new FormBody.Builder.add("key", "the large string").build())
Call call = mOkHttpClient.newCall(builder.build());
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        String output = response.body().string();
        Log.d("okHttp response", output);
    }
});
```

but when this params field length > 500, like 1k, not sure the exactly value, it throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout:

```
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:143)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:162)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:335)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
    at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:90)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:129)
    ... 20 more
```

whether I set timeout:

```java
    int TIMEOUT = 60;
    mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(TIMEOUT,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
```

It always throw SocketTimeoutException after the TIMEOUT I set. It's like it not even send data just wait for timeout.

I tried:

1.Extended TIMEOUT setting value, but it just keep posting and throw timeoutException until the end of time.

2.Tested in postman use the same large data, it uploaded and tooks 1s. The field's length is not too long, just about 8k.

3.Updated the okhttp version from 3.12.0 to the last 4.9.1 now.

But not solved this issue.

I continued to test the program and found something new：

This problem only appears on the Android Pad. When I test with my mobile phone, the same data does not timeout.

1.I tested on Huawei P30 pro(android 10) it works, and not works on Samsung Galaxy Tab active pro(android11) and Xiaomi PAD4(android8.1),Im not sure if this only occurs on pad, or it's just a coincidence.

2.I tested with my Samsung pad and set up a proxy with Charles. When I used the proxy to access the network and want to capture the content data, the program was works. If the proxy was cancelled, the problem reappeared.

Comment: Put a log of `getHostname() + getUrl()` and check the full url. Whats the body type you used in postman?

Comment: The url is right, and POSTMAN use form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded all works. the code can get response in 1s when the "key" field length less than 500, but keep sending when the field length just add to 750, no matter how I expanded timeout set, it just keep sending utils time end.

Comment: is it a localhost server?

Comment: not a localhost server ofcause, its a remote server. I can get response when the post param length less than 500 byte on android, also can get response via postman no matter how long the param length is. just cannot response when i changed this param's length on android. that the only difference.

Comment: Maybe test against a test site like http://httpbin.org/post to see whether it's a general problem, or something your server is doing.

Comment: yes, I test on httpbin.org/post, it as same as my server. it can returns in 1s when I put a 500 byte String param, but still timeout for 60s when i put a 1000 byte String

Comment: I tested and got new phenomena. When I run on mobile phone(HuaweiP30 android10), there is no problem. This problem only occurs on the Android Pad, which is Samsung Galaxy Tab active pro(android11) and Xiaomi PAD4(android8.1)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. it is a network configuration problem. After some comparative tests, I tried hotspot, or cellular network, or change another WiFi. This POST API can succeed. Strangely, there are still differences between mobile phones and PAD under the same WiFi. However, I still don't know whether it is the problem of configuration of router's or pad's WiFi.